# Python - error with a simple socket script

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, connection, netcat

So I wrote a script in Python with the module socket but finally he doesn't work. After searching a few hours for an error (I'm new in Python so it's long for me), I didn't find any so instead I wrote another simple script which works with netcat to have a reverse shell between my host machin (Linux) and my VM (Windows).

My command netcat with Linux :

nc -nvlp 4444

My script in Windows :

```
import socket
connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection.connect(("192.168.1.81", 4444))
```

And after start the listener (netcat), he's listening and after a few seconds, in my Windows machin, the scripts closed itself because he doesn't find anything connection.

I don't know where is the problem, my VM is on the same subnet than my host, I've flushed my iptables in Linux just in case, I'm lost :)

Thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

I just send the script to a friend for trying and it's working, so I think so the problem is in my settings, or somewhere else..